# Is a standard keyboard tray ergonomic?

Tags: keyboard, ergonomics

Is a standard keyboard tray ergonomic, like the ones found in generic Staples computer desks?

[image]

Or is it better to have a larger desk with room for both the monitor and keyboard to rest?

Comment: depends, whats your definition of "standard" I had one that was quite ergonomic and even had a little notch to hold a pad to rest your wrist on. Also the height of the desk and tray play a important role in this.

Comment: The one that comes with those cheapo staples computer desks. :)

Comment: Can you provide a photo of one?

Comment: I don't see image, only blank space

Comment: @Templar You might need to reload -- that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This will depend on the user and the chair.  While the tray may work, it may not, as each case is different.  An adjustable tray and mouse shelf combined with a good, fully adjustable chair will work well in most cases.

Comment: What chair could you recommend to go with that type of desk?

Comment: I would definitely say that you should always go with an adjustable keyboard tray. They are truly wonderful things, but unfortunately a bit pricey.

Comment: Chair is a really personal choice.  Seat depth, back height and all the various adjustments are something you need to try.